# Backend content of page is not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Okay so my problem is that, I am currently working on a website which is already been created using wordpress. My problem is that when you see the website page, there is all the data and everything is present. But when I come to the backend of the page in wordpress its not showing any content at all. I mean its like there has never been the data at all in this page. Its so confusing. Please answer me this. And kindly remember that I am not a good coder so anything that is related to coding please ellaborate it with examples.

Comment: There are many ways to write a page content... What is your page ? Home page ? You should find in your theme directory (on your server, not on your GUI) some php files like "template-xxx.php"' or "page-xxx.php". It may be one of those...

Comment: Probably there must be used of template file. Check template name and find out the file under root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've fixed it.

The problem is in charset of db. 
Open wp-config.php file and just change charset to utf8 & comment the old one.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like the other commenters mentioned, you can also insert content into pages on Wordpress with pages on custom themes.

Remember to back up your site before you make any changes.

Try to change your theme by going to 'Appearance->Themes' in the Wordpress admin window and activating a new theme. Head to the page in question and see if the content is still there. If it isn't, it's being added in a custom theme, which is probably what's happening.

If that's all you need to know, you're all set - otherwise, you can use this process to find what's creating the content:

Go to your Wordpress installation directory (you'll know you're there when you see folders like 'wp-admin' and 'wp-content'), then go to 'wp-content->themes' and see what themes you have installed. You can dig around in the php files there to find the content being created. You'll need to play around with PHP if you want to learn more from there.